# Dio/Flutter - unable to get http error code, invalid error thrown by Dio

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, dio

My code is simple:

```
try {
  var response = await dio.post(url, data: body);
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  throw TextException(Strings.sign_in_error);
}
```

So when server throws error code 401, expected result is dio error type response. Instead, I'm getting DioErrorType default with message "Bad state: no element" and response field set to null. So  I can't event get http error code.

Server response:

```
{"type":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"detail":"access denied"}
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the exact same request works with an http client, such as Postman? It's possible that the response is null when something went wrong in the request

Comment: Also, do you get something out of `e.error`?

Comment: It's fine with default http client. As I said, server gives error code and no response. But I still need error code. `e.error` is `Bad state: No element` So it looks like Dio tries to do something with empty collection and it throws error. Debugger says Dio throws error code http too, bo it's never propagated

Comment: I was wrong, server response is not empty. Question updated

Comment: As a workaround, I added dio option `..options.validateStatus = (status) => true` so now it never throws error when got invalid http code. So it works the samy way as default Dart http client. Then I am able to parse http codes by myself. However, Dio error handling seem to be broken, any ideas are welcome